# Why linked list head (current) keeps getting override by the new value?

Tags: c, file, linked-list

```
while (tempcounter > 0){

        ticket *new=(ticket*)malloc(sizeof(ticket));
        ticket *old=*current;

        fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %s", temps, tempt, tempn, tempi);

        new->visitor.SrNo=temps;
        new->visitor.ticketNo=tempt;
        new->visitor.Name=tempn;
        new->visitor.ID=tempi;
        new->nextPtr=NULL;

        if (*current == NULL){
            *current=new;
            printf("sucess\n");
        } 
        else {
            while (old->nextPtr != NULL) {
                old = old->nextPtr;
            }    
            old->nextPtr = new;
        }
        tempcounter--;
    }
```

First loop of data will get override with second loop of data when it reads from file and when I print the current head out in another loop, it'll only print the last element that has been inserted. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: You need to [edit] and show a [mcve]. There are most likely problems elsewhere in code you didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if current is not changed old will always be reseted to current. You need to reassign current to old or to delete the second line of your loop. Because here all you are doing in the else is setting last one of old to the new one. And then when you restart the while old will reset to become as if nothing happened.
As of the printing. You have to know that printing a linked list is printing the element where your linked list is. That is due to the iteration method wich is made using pointers

Here is a solution to your code problem.

```
while (tempcounter > 0){
    ticket *new=(ticket*)malloc(sizeof(ticket));
    fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %s", temps, tempt, tempn, tempi);
    new->visitor.SrNo=temps;
    new->visitor.ticketNo=tempt;
    new->visitor.Name=tempn;
    new->visitor.ID=tempi;
    new->nextPtr=*current;
    *current = new
    printf("sucess\n");
    tempcounter--;
}
```

To print you can do something like that

```
while (*current != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", current->visitor.SrNo);
    printf("%s ", current->visitor.ticketNo);
    printf("%s ", current->visitor.Name);
    printf("%s ", current->visitor.ID);
*current = current->next;
}
```